# Help with mod_rewrite rule for dynamic url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, dynamic-url

Ugh.. mod_rewrite makes me feel stupid. I just haven't wrapped my brain around it yet. :/

I have this url:

`http://example.com/a/name/`

...that I want to point here:

`http://example.com/a/index.php?id=name`

...where `name` is what is getting passed to `index.php` as the `id` argument.

Anything I've tried results in either a 404 or a 500.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start you off:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule ^/?a/([^/]+)/?$ /a/index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If one rewrite tutorial doesn't work for you, [try another](http://www.google.com/search?q=mod_rewrite+tutorial).

Edit: excluded `index.php` as per Gumbo's suggestion

Comment: Results in 500 error with this:  Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

Comment: Ah, this is just because its trying to rewrite the rewritten URL.. if I start from, say ^/?aa/ then it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Ian You have to exclude the file you are rewriting the request to.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the trailing slash to be optional, you have to exclude the file you are rewriting the request to. Otherwise you will have a nice infinite recursion.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^/a/([^/]+)/?$ /a/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Here any request that starts with `/a/…` but it not `/a/index.php` is rewritten to `/a/index.php`.

But if the trailing slash is mandatory, there is no need to exclude the destination file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/a/([^/]+)/$ /a/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along the lines of

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /a/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]`

would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at this URL:

http://www.dracos.co.uk/code/apache-rewrite-problem/

The presented solutions will work, but there are some caveats explained in the URL, mainly regarding ? and # in the URLs themselves.